# HTML no me autocompleta al utilizar svg y sus determinadas etiquetas

Tags: html, svg

Quiero crear un svg en HTML, al querer escribir las etiquetas, no me brinda la autocompletacion de codigo, tendre que instalar algo o descargar algun plugin? ayuda!

Comment: La "autocompletacion" es una característica del editor que uses, no del lenguaje.
Por ejemplo el visual studio comunity creo que lo tiene.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te sirva esta extensión si usas VS Code [SVG VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jock.svg)